# Smooth scroll to an element based on react-select change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-select

I am using react-scroll to make a smooth scroll onChange of a dropdown (created with react-select). It works the first time, but then doesn't work when I change the dropdown selection again.

Here is the call on the react-select element:

```
<Select
    onChange={select => {
            // scroll to content
            const container = document.querySelector('.container')
            let rect = container.getBoundingClientRect()

            let scroll = Scroll.animateScroll
            scroll.scrollTo((rect.top - 100), {
              smooth: true,
              duration: 250,
              isDynamic: true,
            })
          }} />
```

Has anyone else run into this problem?